# Could not find stanford-postagger.jar jar file at

Tags: python, nltk, stanford-nlp

I am trying to use the StanfordTokenizer `tokenize()` in my script, but it seems like it can't find the jar in the `CLASSPATH` I ordered.

I tried to change the `_JAR = 'stanford-postagger.jar'` to `C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2017.1.2\stanford-postagger-2016-10-31\'stanford-postagger.jar'` but it doesn't seem to work.

This is my script:

```
from nltk.tokenize.stanford import StanfordTokenizer
def AnalyzeText(text):
     t = StanfordTokenizer(path_to_jar='C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2017.1.2\stanford-postagger-2016-10-31\stanford-postagger.jar')
     return t.tokenize(text)
```

[image: This is the error I get]

I do have updated `nltk`. I also downloaded the `stanford-postagger` as you see. I can't understand what the problem is.

Comment: Please consider pasting the traceback in the image as text. That way it is easier to find possible keywords, and it is also easier to read.

Comment: From the traceback it looks like the problem is with finding `java.exe`, not with the jar file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like the ClASSPATH was okay. NLTK needs a JDK 1.8 version.

```
import os
java_path = "C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_131/bin/java.exe"
os.environ['JAVAHOME'] = java_path
```

Answer (score 0):

In Python3, do this once:

```
import urllib.request
import zipfile

# Download the file.
urllib.request.urlretrieve(r'http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/stanford-postagger-full-2015-04-20.zip', r'C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2017.1.2\stanford-postagger-full-2015-04-20.zip')

# Initialize a zipfile object.
zfile = zipfile.ZipFile(r'C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2017.1.2\stanford-pos-2015-04-20.zip')

# Unzip the file.
zfile.extractall(r'C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2017.1.2\stanford-pos')
```

Then:

```
from nltk.tokenize.stanford import StanfordTokenizer

# First we set the direct path to the NER Tagger.
_path_to_jar = r'C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2017.1.2\stanford-pos\stanford-postagger-full-2015-04-20\stanford-postagger.jar'

# Then we initialize the NLTK's Stanford Tokenizer.
st = StanfordTokenizer(path_to_jar= _path_to_jar)

st.tokenize(text)
```